# Coin Change in Java

Tags: java, programming-challenge, change-making-problem

Inspired by a [leetcode exercise](https://leetcode.com/problems/coin-change/), I wrote my own coin changer:

> You are given an integer array coins representing coins of different denominations and an integer amount representing a total amount of money.
>
> Return the fewest number of coins that you need to make up that amount. If that amount of money cannot be made up by any combination of the coins, return -1.
>
> You may assume that you have an infinite number of each kind of coin.
>
> > Example:
> >
> > `Input: coins = [1,2,5], amount = 11`
> >
> > `Output: 3`
> >
> > `Explanation: 11 = 5 + 5 + 1`

**CoinType**

```
public class CoinType implements Comparable<CoinType>{

    private final int value;

    public CoinType(int value){
        this.value = value;
    }
    public int getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "value = "+value;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(CoinType o) {
        return -1 * Integer.compare(value, o.getValue()); //biggest first!
    }
}
```

**CoinTypes**

```
public class CoinTypes {

    private List<CoinType> coinTypes = new ArrayList<>();
    public CoinTypes(int[] samples) {
        coinTypes = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.stream(samples).mapToObj(CoinType::new).toList());
        Collections.sort(coinTypes);
    }

    public List<CoinType> getCoinTypes() {
        return coinTypes;
    }
}
```

**Change** (returned money, my bad english, sorry)

```
public class Change {

    private Map<CoinType, Integer> change = new HashMap<>();
    private int amount;

    public Change(int amount) {
        this.amount = amount;
    }

    public int getRemaining() {
        int sum = change.entrySet().stream().mapToInt(Change::multiply).sum();
        return amount - sum;
    }

    public static int multiply(Map.Entry<CoinType, Integer> entrySet){
        return entrySet.getKey().getValue() * entrySet.getValue();
    }

    public void add(CoinType coinType, int amount) {
        change.put(coinType, amount);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return change.entrySet().stream().map(e -> ""+e.getValue()+" coins of "+e.getKey()).collect(Collectors.joining(","));
    }

    public int getAmountCoins() {
        return change.values().stream().mapToInt(i -> i).sum();
    }

    public boolean hasRemaining() {
        return getRemaining() != 0;
    }
}
```

**CoinChanger**

```
public class CoinChanger {

    private final CoinTypes coinTypes;
    public CoinChanger(int[] coinTypes) {
        this.coinTypes = new CoinTypes(coinTypes);
    }

    public Change change(int result) {
        Change change = new Change(result);
        for(CoinType coinType: coinTypes.getCoinTypes()){
            int amount = change.getRemaining() / coinType.getValue();
            change.add(coinType, amount);
        }
        if(change.hasRemaining()){
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("cannot change to that amount with my coinTypes");
        }
        return change;
    }
}
```

**App** running example

```
public class App{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] coins = {1,2,5}; 
        int amount = 11;

        CoinChanger coinChanger = new CoinChanger(coins);
        try {
            Change change = coinChanger.change(amount);
            System.out.println(change);
        }catch (IllegalArgumentException e){
            System.out.println("cannot give change: "+e);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, and most importantly, this program, as currently written, fails for some inputs where it shouldn't. For example, it can't make change for a value of 11 when using coins of values 2 and 5, even though 3*2 + 1*5 = 11

That aside, I'm not sure the `CoinTypes` class is doing much here. It's just a wrapper around a `List<CoinType>`, only ever interacted with as a way to get to that list. Using the `List<CoinType>` directly seems more appropriate

The `CoinType` class almost feels overkill as well, being a thin wrapper around an `int`. That said, it arguably helps a bit with readability and clarity (`Map<CoinType, Integer>` is more meaningful than `Map<Integer, Integer>`), but I'm still not a huge fan

`Change::multiply` does not interact with the `Change` object's state, and can be `static`. It also does not really seem like part of `Change`'s public-facing API (no object but a `Change` object is expected to ever call it), so I'd argue it should be made `private`

Answer (score 2):

#### Consider testability

It's nice to have an easy way to test a program with various inputs, in this example:

- with coins in reverse order,
- with coins that are *relative primes* such as [2, 5]

With the posted code, I have to change the hardcoded values in the `main` method, then compile and run.

The `main` method could use the first arg as the target amount and the remaining args as the coins to make the program testable without recompilation.

#### Consider input validation

The implementation will behave strangely on some inputs:

- When the target amount is negative, it may return change with negative values
- When there are duplicate coins, it may return incorrect change

#### Improve exception handling

Throwing `IllegalArgumentException` in `main` looks strange now,
because the values used are not real arguments, but hardcoded values.

Also, it's not common to catch `IllegalArgumentException`,
an *unchecked exception*,
and callers of `CoinChanger.change` only know to do this after reading the implementation.
I think a `CoinChangeException` checked exception would be more appropriate here.

#### Do not split key pieces of the algorithm

The essence of the algorithm in the posted code is:

- for each unique coin in descending order

  - remove from the remaining amount the maximum multiples of the coin

This is not easy to find in the posted code,
because the important pieces are too far away from each other:

- `CoinChanger` finds the multiples of coins, but the ordering of coins is not visible there
- `CoinChanger` has `CoinTypes` which performs sorting, but the descending ordering is not visible
- `CoinTypes` has a list of `CoinType`, which have a comparator for reverse ordering

A related issue is that `Change` is used for two purposes:

- Build up the result as coin types and their counts
- Track the state of the computation: the remaining amount to change

The consequence of the above is that to piece together the algorithm,
the reader has to read multiple classes,
and sometimes switch back and forth between classes.

To make the algorithm easy to see,
it would be best to move the descending ordering logic closer to the logic of finding multiples.
For example:

- `CoinChanger` could sort and store the received coins in a `private final int[] coinTypesInDescendingOrder`.
- `CoinTypes` could be renamed `DescendingOrderCoinTypes`, and implement the sorting using a `Comparator`, to make that important responsibility easy to see.

And to move the responsibility of tracking the remaining amount out of `Change` and into `CoinChanger.change`.
Notice that this will have the added benefit of removing from `Change` the unnecessary recomputing of the remaining amount.

#### Implementing `Comparable` in practice

Implementing `Comparable` is most useful for classes that have an obvious logical ordering.
In my experience most of the time there is no single obvious logical ordering,
and it makes more sense to use a `Comparator` with a descriptive name to perform the sorting.

When I think about ordering of coins,
I naturally think of ascending order.
Therefore, instead of making `CoinType` implement `Comparable` with a counter-intuitive logic,
I would not implement the needed ordering in a `Comparator<CoinType>` with a descriptive name.

#### Improve naming

The naming is mostly fine, except some confusing inconsistencies in some variables:

- `CoinTypes` takes `int[] samples`... Why not name that `coins`?
- `CoinChanger.change` takes `int result`... Better to name that `amount` (as does the caller), and rename the local variable `amount` to `count`

#### Java issues

In `CoinTypes` you could avoid creating a new `ArrayList` and `Collections.sort` by using `.sorted()` before calling `.toList()`.

You missed a few member variables that can be `final`:

- `Change.change`
- `CoinTypes.coinTypes`

`Change.multiply` can be `private`,
but actually I would inline it,
because it's only used in place,
and it's less typing that way.

It seems `getAmountCoins` is never used, so it can be removed.

Keep in mind that the purpose of overriding `toString` is not for pretty display, but to help debugging.
So I think the best implementation of `Change.toString` would be simply:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return change.toString();
}
```